# Does Windows Server Active Directory Support single sign-on for web-based saas Applications?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, single-sign-on

I am presently scratching with the features of Windows Azure Active Directory. I came across a feature named single sign-on for web based SaaS applications.

What I am presently aware of is: Windows Azure Active Directory provides single sign-on capability to all the web-based SaaS applications provisioned to the user by the IT-Admin. For example:

> When user opens myapps.microsoft.com with his log-in credentials, he
>   automatically signs in to all the applications provisoned to him by
>   his IT Admin.

My Query is:

> Is This Feature Also Available in Windows Server Active Directory? Is
>   there a way in which when we log-in into our PC, in a domain, it
>   automatically signs us into all the network devices, Applications,
>   Web-based Applications Etc?

Comment: For web apps, I think you'd use ADFS as a gateway? Many web apps support SAML2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible for Windows 10 clients with Azure AD join which are also joined to a domain. In this case the client has SSO to all resources that are trusted by the on-prem DC, and also to the resources trusted by Azure AD.

For older clients, it depends. If you have ADFS, you will get full SSO for all on-prem and cloud resources. If you don't, you will have to log in to AD and then to AAD.